# Hadoop - increasing map tasks in xml doesn't increases map tasks when runs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I added the following in my `conf/mapred-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>4</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
```

But when I run the job, its still runs `2 maps(which is default one)`? How can I force this number to increase?

P.S. I am using `Ubuntu Quad core` box

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running over a small amount of data? It could be that your MapReduce job is running over only one input split and thus does not require more mappers. Try running your job over hundreds of MB of data instead and see if you still have the same issue.

The maximum number of tasks able to run on a single node has nothing to do with the number of map tasks a job has. Your job could be 20 map tasks, while your cluster has 5 map slots, and it will just take longer. Or, your cluster could have 50 map slots, but your job only have 2 map slots.

Answer (score 2):

`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` is the maximum number of tasks a tasktracker can run simultaneously. But when you want to set the number of map tasks for a job as a whole, set `mapred.map.tasks` to 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```

Try that.

Comment: The original query was about the map tasks and not the reduce tasks. The total number of map tasks for a job equals to to the number of the input splits. We can only control the number of map/reduce tasks which can run in ||el on a TaskTracker.

Comment: It is the job that should run with more map tasks and not the whole cluster.